# How can I compile my html content when coming back from some different page links?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs-directive

I am storing the table element (dom element) in service in order retrieve back the inner html. Because when controller scope changes we can not retain the old html table content.

I have written the directive to compile the newly assigned html as below: (compilehtml directive has been added in table tag in html page)

```
myApp.directive('compilehtml', function ($compile) {
     return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
      link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {      
            if(scope.dataServices.tableRefObject)
            {                               
               ele[0].innerHTML=$compile(scope.dataServices.tableRefObject.innerHTML.toStrin g().trim())(scope);
            }
        }
      };
    });
```

I am copying back the inner html and compiling it while copying but still its not able to recognize the directives defined in innerHtml.

Please guide me on what am I missing ? Is it not the way to compile the html ?

Comment: I can not make fiddle for this, sorry for it. Since I am not aware how can I write a scenario where I am changing diff scopes over diff routes. And coming back to same scope.
Note: In table I am dynamically adding rows and columns and also changing the content. So the td's I add, has directive defined in its content which are not getting recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the code below:

```
myApp.directive('compilehtml', function ($compile) {
 return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
  link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {      
        if(scope.dataServices.tableRefObject)
        {  
            ele.html(scope.dataServices.tableRefObject.innerHTML.toString().trim());
            $compile(ele.contents())(scope);   
        }
    }
  };
});
```

I was using ele[0] which was not correct. Now this is working fine.

Hope this helps !